# Facebook Login PHP: Something weird with my logout

Tags: php, facebook, session, authentication, sdk

(Sorry if I have redaction and spelling troubles)

Hi guys, I'm new on Facebook SDK and I have a huge problem (I need to solve it before today).

I'm trying to implement a facebook login in this site:

http://www.woonki.com/usuarios/index.php (Site Lang. is Spanish)

So, I downloaded a code from internet and I implemented that on my site. When the user makes the log-in, it works well!; But when the user makes the log-out, it's still marking the user session (even if the user has logged out of facebook)! In other words, my log-out script doesn't works :(

This is the "fb_logout.php" code

```
<?php 

/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   IdiotMinds - http://idiotminds.com
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
    require '../Connections/fb_config.php';
    if((isset($_SESSION['User']) && !empty($_SESSION['User'])))
    {
       $_SESSION['fb_'.$appID.'_user_id'] = '';
       $_SESSION['fb_'.$appID.'_access_token'] = '';
       session_destroy();
       header('Location: '.$base_url);      
    }

?>
```

So, I tried out my code and the 'if' condition isn't working! I don't know what is happening here, if my SESSION is not a SESSION or vice-versa.

Comment: did you remember to use `session_start()` before you started playing with `$_SESSION`?

Comment: I'm sorry man, that was the problem... I forgot that i was commented on my session_start connect. THANKS and sorry